# Creating an objective-C preprocessor directive that determines if the current language is RTL or LTR

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to build an Objective-C preprocessor directive, that will determine if the current user's preferred language is RTL or LTR - instead of checking it every time I want to display a direction-based layout (UITableView for example), or saving a corresponding boolean in a global scope.

Does anyone have any insight about it ?

Comment: Are your users going to compile your program from source whenever they install it?

Comment: Of course not .. I thought that since I'm using a preprocessor directive to detect ios version - there must be another one for determining what kind of language they prefer...

Comment: That would, of course, detect YOUR language preferences.

Comment: @Guys - a pre-processing directive != not at run-time. I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.

Comment: OK - thanks for your important comments. Is there any efficient way to find out the language direction dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.

Preprocessing precedes compilation.

User's writing/reading direction is determined when they run your program (and may change, so it may also be a mistake to cache).

---

Of course, you could:

```
#define IS_USER_READING_DIRECTION_LTR <#Whatever you use now to determine this dynamically#>
```

…but I don't believe that is your question.